# Triggering delegate method in ViewController from Appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use the AppDelegate to trigger a delegate method in the viewcontroller via and NSTimer. So in the AppDelegate, I basically have:

AppDelegate.h

```
@protocol TestDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)testFunction:(NSString *)testString;

@end

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<TestDelegate> testDelegate;
...
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(trigger:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    return YES;
}

-(void)trigger:(id)sender {
   [self.testDelegate testFunction:self];
}
```

In my view controller I have:

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <TestDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
   ...
   -(void)viewDidLoad {
       self.appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
       self.appDelegate.testDelegate = self;
   }

   -(void)testfunction:(NSString *)testString {
       NSLog(@"%@", testString);
   }
@end
```

when I load the ViewController in my app, nothing happens? I know the NSTimer is successfully firing, but the delegate method isn't being triggered.

Comment: Where do you assign anything to testDelegate ?

Comment: in my appdelegate.h, I have @property (strong, nonatomic) id<TestDelegate> testDelegate;

Comment: oh i see what you mean...

Comment: where can I assign the delegate in this example?

Comment: Whenever you can - you create ViewController and assign it as delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function declaration is:

```
-(void)testFunction:(NSString *)testString;
```

But you call it as:

```
[self.testDelegate testFunction:self];
```

so you are sending `self` to a parameter that is expecting a pointer to an `NSString`, which is obviously incorrect.

Also, rather than using a timer, I'd use GCD like so:

```
double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    if [self.testDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(testFunction:)] {
        [self.testDelegate testFunction:@"Test String"];
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, just curious because i haven't gotten a concise answer, but why GCD over NSTimer? What are the drawbacks of using NSTimer?

Comment: THe other question is why did the original code compile since there is a protocol defined?

Comment: I prefer using a GCD in this case because I'm only firing it once. This way I don't have another property to hold the timer, And I don't have to set up all the code to create the timer either. Also, consider the case where you want the timer to do one thing. You don't need to write a method as the callback, you can write the code in the block, so you can see straight away what the timer will run.

Comment: I saw that, but if there is a defined protocol id<TestDelegate> the compiler should have noticed you sending self to testFunction expecting an NSString

Comment: Maybe it did. Not everyone pays attention to warnings, though. Although I highly recommend building with 0 warnings - what are we, Windows programmers?

Answer (score 1):

Where do you assign your VC as delegate? Is it your VC assigning itself during initialisation/view did load? If you're not doing that I would assign it in ViewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].testDelegate = self;
}
```

Also you would probably want to set the property in AppDelegate weak instead of strong to avoid retaining the VC when/if it is dismissed.

Comment: I just added this to viewcontroller viewdidload, but it still doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: that should be a question acctually

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].testDelegate = self;
```

instead of all that:

```
self.appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.appDelegate.testDelegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

check like

```
if(!testDelegate) {
   [self.testDelegate testFunction:self];
}
```

and if your controller is in your navigation controller then loop through and find your controller alive object and assign delegate.

But I would recommended this kinda functionality using LocalNotification